# Using web.webopenid with web.py to authenticate users

Tags: python, apache, openid, mod-wsgi, web.py

I have a web.py app I'm running through mod_wsgi locally (http://localhost/...).  I've gotten to the point of adding authentication to my app and wanted to use web.py's builtin module.  I started with a brief example found here: http://log.liminastudio.com/programming/howto-use-openid-with-web-py

```
import web, web.webopenid

urls = (
    r'/openid', 'web.webopenid.host',
    r'/', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        body = '''
        <html><head><title>Web.py OpenID Test</title></head>
        <body>
            %s
        </body>
        </html>
        ''' % (web.webopenid.form('/openid'))

        return body

if __name__ == "__main__": app.run()
```

This works well enough running in the terminal and going to http://localhost:8080/.  Another example http://c-farrell.blogspot.com/2010/11/usrbinenv-pythonimport-webfrom-web.html does a similar technique but makes more sense to me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import web
from web import webopenid
urls = (
'/', 'index',
'/openid', 'webopenid.host',
)

... more code ...

class index:
  def GET(self):
    oid = webopenid.status()
    if not oid:
      return 'please log in: ' + \
        webopenid.form('/openid')
    else:
      return 'you are logged in as:' + \
              webopenid.form('/openid')
```

Here's where I get a little lost.  From what I can tell, the argument passed to `form` is the return URL after signing in.  For example, if I put 'http://www.yahoo.com/' it will take me there after every login attempt.  I feel like this should point back to my own controller and just check there, but the convention seems to be to use the web.webopenid.host controller, which I guess handles the id and returns to the base '/' url.  I think I'm getting there, but the status returned is always `None`.

From what I gather then, this is either a code issue, or there's something in my apache configuration that is keeping the authentication from working.  In web.webopenid, the library creates a .openid_secret_key file in the same directory as the web server.  When I run the example code, this gets created.  When I run my code through apache, it does not (at least not in the cgi-bin.  Somewhere else?)  Anyway, if this file isn't being generated or being regenerated every time, it will keep me from logging in.  I believe it's an apache issue as I tried running my app through the web.py webserver and I did get the file created and I can authenticate.  All I can conclude is this file isn't being written and every subsequent query tries a new file and I can never authentication.  Can any apache/mod_wsgi gurus explain to me where this file is being written or if this is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely obvious causes for this were given in answer to same question on mod_wsgi list. See:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/modwsgi/iL65jNeY5jA/KgEq33E8548J

It is probably a combination of the first two, current working directory and Apache user access rights.

Comment: I modified the library to write to directly to /tmp, but still didn't have any success.  I'm not convinced it is a file issue yet.